# Flutter: how to insert a link in a RichText widget

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout

In this [video](https://youtu.be/rykDVh-QFfw) they say you can use a Gesture recognizers in order to create a clickable link in your TextSpan, but I found no examples in the RichText official documentation and in general on internet. Can someone please explain me how to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically is something like this

```
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    children: [
      TextSpan(text: 'Hello'),
        TextSpan(
          text: 'World',
            recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
              ..onTap = () async {
                //Code to launch your URL
              }
        )
      ]
   )
);
```

You can use the [URL launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) to manage the links, that goes like this:

```
const url = 'https://flutter.dev';
if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
} else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
}
```